# UIStackView -- pad leading and trailing space so that subviews remain fixed size/spacing and any padding is before/after subviews

Tags: ios, uistackview

We are wanting to group some buttons in a horizontal UIStackView.  The buttons should be fixed size and fixed spacing between them.  Any padding necessary should be before the first button and after the last button equally.

If we add a button, then it should realign the buttons in a group in the "center" of the stack view.  The closest we've gotten is with alignment = .center and distribution = equal spacing.  But the spacing is not fixed -- it expands the button to button spacing instead of on the ends.

I'm thinking that this should be easy to define, so that any constraints it needs to make are added at the front and back of the list of buttons but we've not been able to get it to work.

Thanks for any hints or clues on how to get there.

Comment: Sounds like you are constraining the left and right sides of the stack view. Don't do that. Just give the stack view a horizontal position but don't constrain its width.